# How do I write an SQL query whose where clause is contained in another query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I have two tables, one for Customer and one for Item.

In Customer, I have a column called "preference", which stores a list of hard criteria expressed as a `WHERE` clause in SQL e.g. `"item.price<20 and item.category='household'"`.

I'd like a query that works like this:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE interpret('SELECT preference FROM customer WHERE id = 1')
```

Which gets translated to this:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE item.price < 20 and item.category = 'household'
```

**Example data model:**

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
cust_id INT  
preference VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE item (  
item_id INT  
price DECIMAL(19,4)  
category VARCHAR  
);
# Additional columns omitted for brevity
```

I've looked up casting and dynamic SQL but I haven't been able to figure out how I should do this.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change my schema instead, as it was getting pretty messy to store the criteria in preferences in that manner.

I restricted the kinds of preferences that could be specified, then stored them as columns in Customer.

After that, all the queries I wanted could be expressed as joins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that preference is the same as my made up item_id column. You may need to tweak it to fit your case. For future questions like this it may pay to give us the table structures you are working with, it really helps us out!

What you are asking for is a subquery:

```
select  * 
from  item 
where item_id in (select 
                    preference 
                from 
                    customer 
                where id = 1)
```

What I would suggest though is a join:

```
select item.* 
from item 
join customer on item.item_id = customer.preference
where item.price<20 and 
    item.category='household'
    customer.id = 1
```

Comment: My `preference` has nothing to do with `item_id` so the first query wouldn't work. Ditto with the `join on` clause of the second example. What I want is to be able to replace the complete `where` clause of your second example with a query. While subqueries let us use single tuples or columns from another query, I want to replace my entire `where` clause using a string stored in another query. Because the `where` clause will vary based on the customer, and I'm assuming it has to be dynamic for that to work.

Comment: @PrashanthChandra: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I see what you are trying to achieve now. Yes, dynamic SQL would be the way to go there, but how that is implemented in PostgreSQL is a bit out of my wheelhouse sorry!